# how can get longitude and langitude with split from json in android kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, maps

So heres my json,

```
"geometry":{
"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[101.167692, -0.011863
    ]
  }
```

i want to take the longitude and langitude, how can i do it ?
my code look like this, i want to put it in my map with marker, but before that i need parse my json into my map

```
private fun getLocationMarker() {
    try {
        val stream = assets.open("sample_map.json")
        val size = stream.available()
        val buffer = ByteArray(size)
        stream.read(buffer)
        stream.close()
        val strContent = String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        try {
            val jsonObject = JSONObject(strContent)
            val jsonArrayResult = jsonObject.getJSONArray("features")
            for (i in 0 until jsonArrayResult.length()) {
                val jsonObjectResult = jsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(i)
                val modelMain = ModelMain()
                val jsonObjectprop = jsonObjectResult.getJSONObject("properties")
                modelMain.strName = jsonObjectprop.getString("name")
                modelMain.strVicinity = jsonObjectprop.getString("description")

                //get lat long
                val jsonObjectGeo = jsonObjectResult.getJSONObject("geometry")
                val jsonObjectLoc = jsonObjectGeo.getJSONArray("coordinates")
                modelMain.latLoc = jsonObjectLoc[1] as Double
                modelMain.longLoc = jsonObjectLoc[0] as Double
                modelMainList.add(modelMain)

            }
            initMarker(modelMainList)
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    } catch (ignored: IOException) {
        Toast.makeText(
            this@MainActivity,
            "Oops, ada yang tidak beres. Coba ulangi beberapa saat lagi.",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to split ? Its an array you can just access them using index however you need to parse it before using

Comment: Oh yeah just realized, thanks